# Подключение SDL2 к проекту Clion

Tags: c++, clion, sdl

[Следовал этому гайду](https://youtu.be/SjH_z0x7dWU), такая вот ошибка:

```
====================[ Build | sdlplot | Debug ]=================================
"D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Глеб\CLionProjects\sdlplot\cmake-build-debug --target sdlplot
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sdlplot.dir/main.cpp.obj
[2/2] Linking CXX executable sdlplot.exe
FAILED: sdlplot.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -g  CMakeFiles/sdlplot.dir/main.cpp.obj -o sdlplot.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libsdlplot.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LC:/libs/SDL/lib/x86 -lSDL2main  -lSDL2  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2main.lib when searching for -lSDL2main
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2main.lib when searching for -lSDL2main
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86\SDL2main.lib when searching for -lSDL2main
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2main.lib when searching for -lSDL2main
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2.lib when searching for -lSDL2
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2.dll when searching for -lSDL2
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2.lib when searching for -lSDL2
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2.dll when searching for -lSDL2
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86\SDL2.lib when searching for -lSDL2
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2.lib when searching for -lSDL2
D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/libs/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2.dll when searching for -lSDL2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Что я должен сделать чтобы исправить ее?

Comment: Вам необходимо собрать библиотеку SDL этим компилятором. Файлы .lib - это для VisualC++

Comment: @user7860670 а как это сделать?

Comment: Копировать dll-ки в `C:\Windows` - огромная глупость.

Comment: Собирать SDL самому не нужно, достаточно скачать версию для MinGW.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а можете подробно обьяснить что надо сделать? Пожалуйста.

Comment: CMake-ом не пробовал собирать, поэтому точно не скажу. Как минимум - скачать зипник со словом `mingw` в названии отсюда: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.24.0